# pandas set value based on previous row only one time for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `df` like this:

```
id  date  target
1      1.1    1
1      2.1    0
2      1.1    1
3      1.1    1 
3      2.1    0
```

I want to change the `target` column that if in the pervious row its appear "1" and its the same `id`, change the next row, and only it, to 1

desire output:

```
id    date target
1      1.1    1
1      2.1    1
2      1.1    1
3      1.1    1 
3      2.1    1
```

what I tried:

```
def change_df(frame):
    for row in range(frame.shape[0]) :
        if frame["target"][row]==1 and frame.loc[row+1,"id"]==frame.loc[row,"id"] :
                frame.loc[row+1,"target"]=1
    return frame
```

but its change all the rows( because of the loop )
TNX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group` the dataframe on `id` then `shift` the column `target` and compare it to `1` to create a boolean mask, then use boolean indexing with this mask to update the values in `target` column to `1`:

```
m = df.groupby('id')['target'].shift().eq(1)
df.loc[m, 'target'] = 1
```

---

```
>>> df

   id  date  target
0   1   1.1       1
1   1   2.1       1
2   2   1.1       1
3   3   1.1       1
4   3   2.1       1
```